# How to trim object properties in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, object

I have an object `$obj` as

```
$obj->{' Property1'} = " value1";
$obj->{'Property2 '} = "value2 ";
```

I want to get this object `$obj` as

```
$obj->{'Property1'} = "value1";
$obj->{'Property2'} = "value2";
```

I am able to trim all the values using

```
foreach($obj as $prop => &$val)
{
     $val = trim($val);
}
```

but doing this (below) causing an error

```
foreach($obj as &$prop => &$val)
{
     $prop = trim($prop);
     $val = trim($val);
}
```

Please tell a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try to split key value pair 
 `code` 
foreach($obj as $prop => $val)
{
     unset($obj->{$prop});
     $obj->{trim($prop)} = trim($val);
}
 `code`

Comment: @nu1_ww Yes I did. It didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference a key.

What you have to do is unset it, and set the trimmed version like this:

```
<?php
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->{' Property1'} = " value1";

foreach($obj as $prop => $val)
{
     unset($obj->{$prop});
     $obj->{trim($prop)} = trim($val);
}

var_dump($obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

A little comment to Daan's answer. In his case script will fall into infinite loop if $obj have more than one property. So a working code looks like this.

```php
<?php
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->{' Property1'} = " value1";
$obj->{'Property2 '} = "value2 ";

$newObj = new stdClass;

foreach($obj as $prop => $val)
{
     $newObj->{trim($prop)} = trim($val);
}

$obj = $newObj;

unset($newObj);

var_dump($obj);
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you're trying to trim the property of the object. You can't do that.

That would work for an array, but not for an object. If you need to alter the properties of an object you need to change the properties of the class.